# Client Socket problems on Android

Tags: android, sockets, client

```
    package com.example.handy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private EditText ipaddress;
    private Button connect;
    private Button wipe;
    private static String myIp;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
        ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipaddress_felid);

        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        wipe =(Button) findViewById(R.id.wipe);



        //Button press event listener
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
                 setMyIp(ipaddress.getText().toString());
                // myComs.sending_data(getMyIp() , "Got connected");
                try
                 {
                     InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
                     Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
                     OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
                     PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);





                     p.println("You are connected");
                     p.flush();

                     readContacts();
                     readSms();
                     new Incomingdata().execute();



                 }



                 catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                 {
                    ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


             }


         });
        wipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
                String kill = "5";
                 myComs.sending_data(MainActivity.getMyIp(), kill);
                 finish();

             }
             });
    }
private class Incomingdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        setMyIp(ipaddress.getText().toString());
        try
        {   
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
            Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
            while(s.isConnected())
            {
                String input =r.nextLine();
                System.out.println(""+input);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

So this is where i am, i can flush data out but can not seem to receive it back in from the server i am fairly new at this and have got help in the past from this site. I am really stuck and running out of time

Any help would be great

And Thank you

Comment: To me that shouldn't work, aren't you getting an IOException (check logcat!)?

Comment: Hi Pescis.... Actually no IOException but my message(input) is not coming out either please help i am at the very end of my know how here

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of Socket, one is used for connecting to a host, and the other one is used to listen for connections. What you want to do is before trying to connect, make a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) that listens to incoming connections to a specific port number and wait for a new connection, as such:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
```

This should be done in your AsyncTask before trying to connect to it (`accept()` is blocking so it will wait for an incoming connection). So, changing the following two lines with the above and calling the AsyncTask before trying to connect to it should do the trick:

```
        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
        Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
```

Comment: right it seems to going into the doInbackground but when my server sends a message nothing!!